# SUM a range of cells (sometimes string, sometimes numbers), parsing the cell if it is a string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to get the sum of a column of cells, which sometimes contains numbers and sometimes contains a string with numbers in it. I've found that the formula

```
=arrayformula(sum(0+iferror(regexextract(B2:B, "[\d\.]+"))))
```

works for parsing strings into numbers and SUMming them, but because of regex, it ignores anything that is not a string (ie, already a number). An example set of data might be:

```
B2: 1000.56
B3: $254.32
B4: ~125
B5: 321.43
B6: ~1030
```

The result of which should be

```
1000.56 + 254.32 + 125 + 321.43 + 1030 = 2731.31
```

Using the above formula though, the values of B2 and B5 are ignored, as they are not a string, and so regex will not parse them

Is this possible, or would it end up just being completely convoluted?

Comment: @user0 oops, updated with an expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(B2:B; "#.##"); 
                                                         "[\d+\.]+"); 
                                                         "."; ",")); ))
```

column **B** will be converted to **`TEXT`** values with keeping number format **`"#.##"`** and then extracted numbers are treated with **`SUBSTITUTE`** to replace **`.`** with **`,`** (otherwise result would be rounded to **`2730`**)  then it's fed to **`ARRAYFORMULA`** and to get rid of **`#N/A`** error from blank cells, all is wrapped in **`IFERROR`** and finally summed with **`SUMPRODUCT`** returning requested **`2731.31`**

[image]

---

**american syntax:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(B2:B, "#.##"), "[\d+\.]+")), ))
```

Comment: Hmm, I've entered your exact formula but can't replicate the result; only the strings are being added. Any idea what I did wrong? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tuNaOlBKcKCcV7DpK3k3Z-NzoT6TVYQU_ls-g_v5C14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, you are using US version of spreadsheets which calculates by different means than European spreadsheet. I've edited my answer - use 2nd formula.